# How can I capture or enforce REST API coverage from Java unit tests?

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, code-coverage, raml

Having embraced code coverage as a concept and driven our code in general to have 70%+ line coverage, management are now interested in REST API coverage.

We're currently experimenting with defining our JAX-RS REST resources using RAML and using code generation to build the JAX-RS models and interfaces. Clearly RAML can define the set of resources that should be available by which methods, indicates which MIME types can be accepted and produced, and which status codes are acceptable responses to any given invocation.

Are there any tools or test frameworks that I could use to track a set of unit tests and ensure that all applicable resources have been exercised, all status codes have been generated etc.?

Not sure whether it's better to boil this down to a number and track against a threshold / over time; or whether to just log unit test failure when the coverage is incomplete.  Happy to consider either type of solution for now!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a specific tool that would do that. If none is available, I suggest just measuring code coverage of the generated code. It would probably be easy to find untested resources by looking for resource-implementing classes with lower than average coverage (even if there is uncovered code in a well-tested generated class).

I doubt that you could achieve "status code coverage" for every resource by this approach, since any reasonable API implementation will implement some error statuses in a generic way in one place, but then again maybe you don't really need that if you're covering all of the generated code.